# Receive form content from React app hosted in firebase

Tags: reactjs, forms, firebase, email, create-react-app

I'm learning React and I'm trying to get an email from a simple form inside a basic React app.

I used to use PHP to acomplish that but I know is not possible to do that on Firebase.

I was looking for a solution, but I can't find it. I found some old NPM packages but nothing "easy" to use or outdated. Is there any way to process Form content and receive that content in my email account?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is, of course, there is... You can submit a form and store the data in FB... But your question is too wide and vague... You're asking for a tutorial, not a specific question...

Comment: Try giving formspree a shot: https://formspree.io/

React can handle this in the front-end, it's free, and there's no need to use a firebase cloud function (which would be the other alternative)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!
Maybe is not clear the answer, but my idea is to have something very simple to use. I just took a look on formspree.io and it looks similar to what I was looking for. Thanks @MikeAbeln!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I'm using https://formsapi.jabwn.com
It is more flexible than https://formspree.io and is 100% free.